# The jmeter httpclient4 is causing ephemeral TCP ports exhaustion whereas httpclient3 is not causing in the windows machine

Tags: jmeter, apache-httpclient-4.x, jmeter-5.0

I am running a load test with 600 users using httpclient-3 & httpclient-4 implementation in windows server 2012R2 machine. During the httpclient-4 test after 200 users ramped-up I am facing the ephemeral TCP ports exhaustion, this is not occurring even when I run 1000 users with httpclient-3.

I understand there is a workaround like increasing the ephemeral ports and enabling fast recycling TIME_WAIT sockets to resolve the issue.

I am curious to know is there anyway with the help of jmeter properties can we resolve the ephemeral TCP ports exhaustion.

Error: Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException,Non HTTP response message: Address already in use